# import Google API client spring gradle

Tags: java, gradle, google-api, google-api-java-client

I am looking to use `com.google.api.services.admin.directory.model.User`. I followed the setup directions and cannot find this package. I am currently doing the following in my `build.gradle`:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    // Google API Client
    implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.30.0'
}
```

I am only able import `com.google.api.client.*`

Comment: Have you tried this: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/setup

Comment: @ankitbeniwal yes, It is still not working for me